# "Application-defined or object-defined error" when inserting row

Tags: excel, vba, insert, row

I've completed parsed my code and found that the error is in this line of code, but I have no idea why:

```
Range(c).Resize(tmp_n).EntireRow.Insert
```

Where `c` is defined as string that looks like : `"A3"` or some other row and `tmp_n` is simply an integer.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and post further details about your problem

Comment: Hi. Could you please provide the exact error in your answer and - if possible- mor code that the line lies within ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message and lack of surrounding code I would say that your tmp_n variable either doesn't have a value or is declared as a String.